# Year:Location Inflation / CoL calculator?

Tags: inflation

Is there a calculator or standard method of computation where you could get the relative difference in spending power of X USD in a given city/year from a given city/year?

For example, what would be the relative increase/decrease in spending power of ($10,000 in San Francisco Ca, 2022) to (10,000 in Phoenix Az, 1999)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard method. It is called Purchasing Power Parity (PPP) or in case it is for region it is sometimes called Regional Price Parity (RPP).

I found [this dataset](https://www.numbeo.com/quality-of-life/region_rankings.jsp?title=2021&displayColumn=1&region=019) that has purchasing power index for some cities, but only largest cities are included.